# Wallaby.js not working with jasmine callFake(...)?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, visual-studio-code, wallaby.js

## Problem

`wallaby.js` seems not to be working with jasmine `callFake`. I want to use the arguments passed to the original function inside the the "fake" function. But I always get `undefined` with `wallaby`.

The test below works when running `jasmine` directly, but breaks when running via `wallaby`.

Did this happen with anyone else?
Any ideas on how to fix it?

## Test

```
it('test callFake and wallaby', async () => {
  // Arrange
  const myObj = {
    myFunc: (a) => a + 1,
  };

  spyOn(myObj, 'myFunc')
    .and.callFake(arg => arg);

  // Act
  const result = myObj.myFunc(1);

  // Assert
  expect(result).toBe(1);
});
```

[image]

## Related info

#### Wallaby.js configuration file

```
module.exports = (wallaby) => {
  return {
    files: [
      'src/**/*.js',
      'migrations/*',
      'test/_helpers/*',
      'seeds/*',
      'config/*',
      { pattern: '.env', instrument: false },
    ],

    tests: [
      'test/**/*.spec.js',
    ],

    compilers: {
      '**/*.js': wallaby.compilers.babel(),
    },

    testFramework: 'jasmine',

    env: {
      type: 'node',

      params: {
        env: 'NODE_ENV=test;MONGODB_CONQUERY=mongodb://localhost:27017/athena-test',
      },
    },
    workers: {
      initial: 1,
      regular: 1,
      restart: true,
    },

    setup: (/* wallaby */) => {
      require('dotenv').load({ path: '.env' }); // eslint-disable-line
      require('./test/_helpers/dropDatabase'); // eslint-disable-line
    },

    teardown: (/* wallaby */) => {
    },
  };
};
```

#### Code editor or IDE name and version

Visual Studio Code v1.21.1

#### OS name and version

OSX 10.13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in Jasmine 2.x support in wallaby [it is fixed no](https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/1597#issuecomment-377766741)w.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

I used a reference to the spy inside the `callFake` function. See on the code below:

```
it('test callFake and wallaby', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const myObj = {
      myFunc: (a) => a + 1,
    };

    const spy = spyOn(myObj, 'myFunc')
      .and.callFake(
        () => spy.calls.argsFor(0)[0]
      );
    // Act
    const result = myObj.myFunc(1);

    // Assert
    expect(result).toBe(1);
  });
```

But I still think this is not the proper behaviour.